# How can I combine two csv files into one, by adding one column to the end of the first one?

Tags: python, csv, append

I simply need to add the column of the second CSV file to the first CSV file.

Example CSV file #1

> Time Press RH Dewpt Alt
>
> Value  Value Value Value Value

For N number of rows.

Example CSV file #2

> SmoothedTemperature
>
> Value

I simply want to make it

> Time Press RH Dewpt Alt SmoothedTemperature
>
> Value  Value Value Value Value Value

Also one has headers the other does not.

Here is sample code of what I have so far, however the output is the final row of file 1 repeated with the full data set of File #2 next to it.

```
##specifying what they want to open
File = open(askopenfilename(), 'r')
##reading in the other file

Averaged = open('Moving_Average_Adjustment.csv','r')
##opening the new file via raw input to write to
filename = raw_input("Enter desired filename, EX: YYYYMMDD_SoundingNumber_Time.csv; must end in csv")
New_File = open(filename,'wb')



R = csv.reader(File, delimiter = ',')

## i feel the issue is here in my loop, i don't know how to print the first columns
## then also print the last column from the other CSV file on the end to make it mesh well

Write_New_File = csv.writer(New_File)
    data = ["Time,Press,Dewpt,RH,Alt,AveragedTemp"]
    Write_New_File.writerow(data)
    for i, line in enumerate(R):
        if i <=(header_count + MovingAvg/2):
            continue
    Time,Press,Temp,Dewpt,RH,Ucmp,Vcmp,spd,Dir,Wcmp,Lon,Lat,Ele,Azi,Alt,Qp,Qt,Qrh,Qu,Qv,QdZ=line
for i, line1 in enumerate(Averaged):
    if i == 1:
        continue
    SmoothedTemperature = line1
Calculated_Data = [Time,Press,Dewpt,RH,Alt,SmoothedTemperature]
Write_New_File.writerow(Calculated_Data)
```

Comment: A rule that works for me is "Before, put it in the screen. If you can put the desired output in the screen, you can put it into a file"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go down this path, `pandas` makes csv manipulation very easy. Say your first two sample tables are in files named `test1.csv` and `test2.csv`:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> test1 = pd.read_csv("test1.csv")
>>> test2 = pd.read_csv("test2.csv")
>>> test3 = pd.concat([test1, test2], axis=1)
>>> test3 
   Time   Press  RH   Dewpt  Alt  SmoothedTemperature
0      1      2    3      4    5                    6

[1 rows x 6 columns]
```

This new table can be saved to a `.csv` file with the DataFrame method `to_csv`.

If, as you mention, one of the files has no headers, you can specify this when reading the file:

```
>>> test2 = pd.read_csv('test2.csv', header=None)
```

and then change the header row manually in `pandas`.

Comment: I cannot use panda. Unfortunately this code must be generic enough that it can be used by different people at 6 different universities without needing to download anything.